# How do I know if this code is actually working?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

I'm a first time app builder and I found this code on here, it builds successfully but when I press the button to execute it on the simulator it doesn't send the image to my photo album on the simulator, but it doesn't send back any error messages or crash either. So I was trying to find out how would I know if this code will work properly in the app that I'm building?

Comment: run it on your phone and check your photo album? what's the problem?

Comment: Try defining a `completionTarget` so you can capture an error if one is returned https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Comment: @BryanChen, as I said, its my first time ever trying to do this, Im learning from an online course, I didn't know that you could run it on an actual phone, they never mentioned that

Comment: what? you was thinking the iOS code you wrote won't be able to run on phone? then what is the point of writing it?

Comment: No, I know that it will run on the iPhone, but I didn't know that you could run it on a phone before you put it in the app store, @BryanChen, I thought the simulator was the only way to see the functionality of the app

Comment: Make sure the event is captured first. If you are using Interface Builder to build the button, you should have `@IBAction` in front of the method and then link on IB.

Comment: @BryanChen, thanks for the answer because now Im testing the app on my phone, the code still doesnt work right but at least I see that the rest is doing what it's supposed to do and the graphics are nice

Comment: This is what I have in the code--------------------------

@IBAction func sendStats(sender: AnyObject) {
     
        func screenShotMethod() {
            //Create the UIImage
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            //Save it to the camera roll
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        }

Answer (score -1):

try this. you should add UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

```
    func screenShotMethod() {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
```

Comment: You’re right that specifying the scale matters, but that’s not the problem here—if that were the only issue, the image would still be in the camera roll, just blurry.

Comment: Doesn't break anything but the screenshot doesn't go to the camera roll

Comment: I replaced the your code back with the original code and this is what shows up in the output

"Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."

Comment: do you present any viewcontroller ?
UIImagePickerController ?
your view controller ? 
or you use this function viewdidload ?